# I feel that the 1st argument of Enum.Format() is a bit redundant

Tags: c#, types, enums, format, arguments

I've got the code blow:

```
enum Days
{
    day1,
    day2,
    day3
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Enum.Format(typeof(Days), Days.day2, "D"));
    }
}
```

I feel that 1st argument of Enum.Format() is redundant: because the 2nd argument already specified the type of Enum, so compiler will have the information that the type of "day2" is "Days". Then why compile doesn't deduce that the 1st argument to be "typeof(Days)" for it self, why I have to specify it?

In other words, I mean, if .net function of Enum.Format only have 2 arguments, why can't it be? Type can be know from the value argument.

Comment: You could pass an altogether different value for the second argument, such as any integer value, not just the enum value.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: `Format` isn't a generic function, it receives an `object` value. It does *not* know the type unless you specify it. The reason for this is that enum values are more-or-less labels on some underlying numeric value. You can pass an underlying value (eg an int) wherever an enum is used

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The two parts of your argument are totally disconnected. A boxed enum value maintains its type. The only case where the type is really needed is if you want to use the underlying type (the `int`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can use the underlying type of the `enum` in the `value` parameter, like:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Foo = 1
}

string str = Enum.Format(typeof(MyEnum), 1, "G"); // Foo
```

But note that:

```
public enum MyEnum : long
{
    Foo = 1
}

string str = Enum.Format(typeof(MyEnum), 1L, "G");
```

As I've written, you have to use the underlying type! So in this case, `long`.

Very indirectly this is spelled out in [Enum.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.format.aspx):

> ArgumentException: The type of *value* is not an underlying type of *enumType*.

So implicitly, if *value* is of the underlying type of *enumType*, then there is no exception and some result is returned.